# Why are my persimmon leaves getting all brown and turning brittle?

Tags: leaves, damage

[image: My trees are all looking like this.What could it be, N.W. Fl Panhandle.]

My trees are all looking like this.What could it be, N.W. Fl Panhandle.These are supposed to be Persimmon trees. Besides the black the leaves have become very brittle.

Comment: are they getting enough, or too much water?

Comment: been raining a lot but we are on 265 feet of sand (fl sand hills), drains very well. it's only this type of tree, the oaks,peach and others are fine.